# node js child process timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js

Need to know, how can I tackle the child process problem in Node JS. Basically, I need to convert the full pdf file into a jpeg. My process is getting killed. Most of the time files conversion is getting failed. How can I handle the long-running process? once the job is finished. I need to add there reference in the database. Could you please help.

```
const path = require('path');
const cp = require('child_process');

const src = path.join(__dirname, `/pdf-inputs/git.pdf`);
const exp = path.join(__dirname, `/jpg-outputs/git/git-%2d.jpg`);
const density = 300;

class Converter {
    constructor(src, exp, den) {
        this.src = src;
        this.exp = exp;
        this.density = den;
    }
    start() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const child = cp.spawn('convert', ['-density', '300', `${this.src}`, `${this.exp}`], {
                detached: true,
                stdio: 'ignore',
            });
            console.log('process started =======> ', this)

            child.stdout.on('data', data => {
                console.log('process sucessful =======> ')
                return resolve (data);
            });

            child.stderr.on('data', err => {
                console.log('imagemagic process failed =======> ')
                return reject(err);
            })
            child.on('error', (err) => {
                console.log('child process error ========> ', err);
            })
            child.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
                console.log(`child process exited with code: ${code} and signal ${signal}`)})
            })
    }
}


const c = new Converter(src, exp, density);
c.start().then(r => console.log('r ==> ', r)).catch(e => console.log('e ==> ', e));
```

~ Meet

Comment: any error ?? try without `detached: true,  stdio: 'ignore',` these prop

Comment: without detach, the process is getting killed. so I read about detached prop which makes child process independent of the parent. with detach and unref .. process starts but no conversion is happening. cpu reaches 50% for awhile and then I cant see process.

Comment: i feel lile you have to pass context , convert cant be recognize or use  string generated from `'convert', ['-density', '300', `${this.src}`, `${this.exp}` to test on terminal

Comment: I tried hardcoding it ... same result